# SharePoint 2013 document co-authoring is not working with office client application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, co-authoring

We have SharePoint 2013 on-premises setup with office web apps. Document co-authoring works when multiple users are editing same word document in browser but if they open and edit into office word client application (Tested with both - Office 2010,2013) any single user can edit at a time. Another user gets read only document and unable to save changes.

Is there any extra configuration needed? Are we missing anything?

Comment: helped some solution to you?

Answer (score 0):

i think its "by design":

Check out – When a user checks out a document for editing, the document is locked for editing by that user. This prevents co-authoring. Do not enable the Require Check Out feature in document libraries in which co-authoring will be used. By default, Require Check Out is not enabled in SharePoint Server 2013. Users should not check out documents manually when co-authoring is being used. For more information, see Set up a library to require check-out of files.
more on link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718249(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

i tried it on *SharePoint 2013 Server* with my colleague, but you should use **MS Office 2016**. This version of Office has capability to edit documents on client side in co-authoring.

[image: Co-authoring on document saved on SharePoint 2013 Server with Office 2016]

[image: Co-authoring on document saved on SharePoint 2013 Server with Office 2016]

I hope this helps to You! :)