# Multiple users accessing same form

Tags: sharepoint-server

We store Word macro letters for our examiners to use on SharePoint. Can multiple people open the same letter at the same time? They do not save their changes, as the letters are templates, where they enter their info, then print the letter and close the document without making actual changes to the template. Recently we've run into a second user receiving a "read only" error message that someone else has locked the document. However, our end users do not have the ability to actually edit the letters, only use them. Is this a case of two people trying to open the same letter at the exact same time - and if that person who received the error closes it out and tries to reopen they'll be fine?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint allows multiple users to edit files at the same time.

You need to confirm if a user has checked out the document. If someone forgets to close a document or check it in, other users may be locked out indefinitely.

If no user checks out the document, check your version of office and recommend that you use office2016.

This version of Office has capability to edit documents on client side in co-authoring.
Versions of office2010 and 2013 may not support this feature.

You can refer to this similar situation below:

[SharePoint 2013 document co-authoring is not working with office client application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222929/sharepoint-2013-document-co-authoring-is-not-working-with-office-client-applicat)